# Is $(E \cup F ) - (E \cap F)=( E \setminus F) \cup ( F \setminus E)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is  $(E \cup F ) - (E \cap  F)=( E \setminus F) \cup ( F \setminus E)?$  where $E$ and $F$ are nonempty set .

Im not  getting in my head .

Any hints/solution

Comment: Why are you using the two symbols $-$ and $\setminus$?

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram. This is sometimes called the symmetric difference or XOR of the two sets.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net......okss that mean  -  and \  has  same  meaning ? am i right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. You can refer to [Symmetric difference of two sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) for nice examples and definitions.